# Array of strings match against string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to filter out words from a list of Tweets, if there are more than two occurrences of a word in the array then exit out of the loop.

Say I have a string `I was following someone the other day that looked a bit grumpy`

I have an array of strings:

```
[  
  "followback",
  "followers",
  "grumpy cat",  
  "gamergate",
  "quotes",
  "facts",
  "harry potter"
]
```

Is there a way I can match the phrase `grumpy cat` where it wont be picked up by `.indexOf` which would just match `grumpy`?

```js
const yourstring = 'I was following someone the other day that looked a bit grumpy'

const substrings = [  
  "followback",
  "followers",
  "grumpy cat",  
  "gamergate",
  "quotes",
  "facts",
  "harry potter"
]

let len = substrings.length;

while(len--) {
  if (yourstring.indexOf(substrings[len])!==-1) {
    console.log('matches: ', substrings[len])
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to mach `grumpy` or `cat`?

Comment: What then is the use of having `grumpy cat` together in one string? Why not store it in your array as two separate words?

Comment: What are you trying to tell us with the _more than two occurrences of a word_ prerequisite ?

Comment: Because I want to match "grumpy cat" not "cat" or "grumpy"

Comment: So, you are saying that in the example you do not want to have a match, then? (since it does not have "grumpy cat")

Answer (score 2):

You could just do a for loop.

```
for (var x = 0; x<substrings.length; x++) {
   if (substrings[x] == 'your string') {
      // do what you want here
   }
}
```

If your looking for an exact string then just do above and that should work. IndexOf would work if you are trying to match partial strings to a string in your array. But I would stick with the for loop and exact match

Answer (score 0):

You can split the substrings into arrays of words by using `split(' ')`, and then check if any of the words is included in `yourstring` by using the `includes` method.

```js
const yourstring = 'I was following someone the other day that looked a bit grumpy';

const substrings = [  
  "followback",
  "followers",
  "grumpy cat",  
  "gamergate",
  "quotes",
  "facts",
  "harry potter"
];

console.log(substrings.filter(x => x.split(' ').some(y => yourstring.includes(y))));
```

Here's how you can do the same using the Ramda library:

```js
const yourstring = 'I was following someone the other day that looked a bit grumpy';

const substrings = [  
  "followback",
  "followers",
  "grumpy cat",  
  "gamergate",
  "quotes",
  "facts",
  "harry potter"
];

const anyContains = x => R.any(R.flip(R.contains)(x));

console.log(R.filter(R.compose(anyContains(yourstring), R.split(' ')), substrings));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```